# converting int to/from System.Numerics.BigInteger in C#

Tags: c#, casting, biginteger

I have a property that returns `System.Numerics.BigInteger`. When I casting the property to int, I got this error.

`Cannot convert type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' to 'int'`

How can I convert int to/from `System.Numerics.BigInteger` in C#?

Comment: How are you going to deal with values too large to fit into an `int`?

Comment: Can you add some code? BigInteger provides an [explicit conversion operator for `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268292.aspx), so `(int)someBigInteger` should work.

Comment: @Oded : It's pretty temporary code to test this and that. The BigInteger is actually not that big.

Comment: I guess it would be rude to "steal" the answer from dtb - maybe you (@dtb) should propse this as an answer...

Comment: @dtb : The code is pretty simple : return (int) DataItem.IntegerWordLength; and I got an error message. IntegerWordLength is a type of BigInteger.

Comment: Why return a BigInteger if it fits in a regular integer to begin with?

Comment: Are you sure you really need the BigInteger type?  Why not use a signed int or signed long?

Comment: @Jesus: Just an educated guess, but it may be from a database or similar source.

Comment: that would only happen IF the value is too big or too small... or there is somthing in the code/interface of `DataItem.IntegerWordLength`and/or the signature of the method executing the `return` which somehow interferes with all this... in that case you need to show some source

Comment: @Evan But using BigNum in a database where int fits is kind of odd to me :\

Comment: @Jesus. Agreed, but some people think bigger is better. It's a compromise; risk overflow or increase size.

Comment: Just to be completely sure: you are on .Net 4, right? You're not using some other implementation of the class?

Comment: @svick: `System.Numerics` is only available in .NET 4 and Silverlight.

Comment: @Evan, the MS implementation is. But there's nothing stopping anybody from writing their own implementation of `System.Numerics.BigInteger` for older versions.

Comment: in adding try to follow this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268292.aspx#Y600 Regards.

Comment: @svick: But it would not be able to share the same namespace.

Comment: @Evan I guess but if he's having to convert to int then you're going to get an overflow anyways. Why not just handle the BigInteger value in the code as well then?

Comment: @Jesus: Good point. I don't have an explanation for that one!

Comment: @Evan, why not? There is no such class under, say, .Net 3.5, so I am free to create it myself, if I target that version of the framework.

Comment: @svick: Even if you do create the class yourself, it will not share the `System.Numerics` namespace.

Comment: @Evan, `namespace System.Numerics { struct BigInteger {} }` There, I have created my own `System.Numerics.BigInteger`. How does it not share the namespace?

Comment: @svick: True. I didn't realize that was feasible, but it is strongly discouraged by Microsoft, not to mention uncommon and deceptive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [conversion from BigInteger to Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268292.aspx) is explicit, so just assigning a `BigInteger` variable/property to an `int` variable doesn't work:

```
BigInteger big = ...

int result = big;           // compiler error:
                            //   "Cannot implicitly convert type
                            //    'System.Numerics.BigInteger' to 'int'.
                            //    An explicit conversion exists (are you
                            //    missing a cast?)"
```

This works (although it might throw an exception at runtime if the value is too large to fit in the `int` variable):

```
BigInteger big = ...

int result = (int)big;      // works
```

---

Note that, if the `BigInteger` value is boxed in an `object`,  you cannot unbox it and convert it to `int` at the same time:

```
BigInteger original = ...;

object obj = original;      // box value

int result = (int)obj;      // runtime error
                            //   "Specified cast is not valid."
```

This works:

```
BigInteger original = ...;

object obj = original;            // box value

BigInteger big = (BigInteger)obj; // unbox value

int result = (int)big;            // works
```

Comment: @svick: Which one? I get this: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Numerics.BigInteger' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @svick: Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. I think I found the problem now. Will update my answer.

Comment: Unboxing `BigInteger` as `int` throws `InvalidCastException` with the message “Specified cast is not valid.” Which, again, isn't the error OP reported.

Comment: Hmm... that still not the same error. I'm out of ideas. OP needs to show more code.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some choices that will convert BigInteger to int

```
BigInteger bi = someBigInteger;
int i = (int)bi;
int y = Int32.Parse(bi.ToString());
```

Watch Out though if the BigInteger value is too large it will throw a new exception so maybe do

```
int x;
bool result = int.TryParse(bi.ToString(), out x);
```

Or

```
try
{
    int z = (int)bi;
}
catch (OverflowException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Or

```
int t = 0;
if (bi > int.MaxValue || bi < int.MinValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oh Noes are ahead");
}
else
{
    t = (int)bi;
}
```

Comment: This might work, but converting between two integer types by converting to/from string is not exactly a good choice. And, in this case, it just fixes the symptoms instead of the actual problem.

Comment: You seem sort of competent, I must take you as my apprentice.

Answer (score 1):

Having the int.Parse method only works if the initial BigInteger value would fit anyway.  If not, try this:

```
int result = (int)(big & 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Ugly?  Yes.
Works for any BigInteger value?  Yes, as it throws away the upper bits of whatever is there.

Comment: What would this do for negative numbers?

Comment: Okay, when running through the bitwise operation outside of C#, it should work fine.  However, inside C# it throws a system overflow exception for negative numbers.  Not sure why.

Comment: Whether you're doing this in C# or VB, `BigInteger big = 3_000_000_000u; (int)(big & 0xFFFFFFFF)` fails because 3_000_000_000u fits in `uint` and is less than 0xFFFFFFFF but overflows `int`. One [correct way to truncate to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74989790/how-to-truncate-a-biginteger-to-int-long-uint-ulong?noredirect=1#comment132335047_74989790) is `unchecked((int)(uint)(big & uint.MaxValue))`.

Answer (score 1):

By trying to improve the @lee-turpin answer when casting negative numbers, I came with a similar solution, but in this case without the issue with negative numbers. In my case, I was trying to have a 32-bit hash value from a BigInteger object.

```
var h = (int)(bigInteger % int.MaxValue);
```

Still ugly, but it works with any BigInteger value. Hope it helps.