# Convert boxed BigInteger to other type

Tags: c#

I have `BigInteger` boxed in `object`. How can I convert this variable to other numeric types, like `int`, `byte` and other way around?

Also I want this conversion to work for all types without specifying type.

`BigInteger` does not implement `IConvertible`, so `Convert.ChangeType` cannot help here. Afaik it exposes only explicit conversion operator, so only way I see is to manually check if type is `X` and cast.

Unlike [converting int to/from System.Numerics.BigInteger in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127565/converting-int-to-from-system-numerics-biginteger-in-c-sharp) i want to be convert to multiple types at runtime.

Example code:

```
ConvertInteger(object integerObj, Type targetType)
{
   ///
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [converting int to/from System.Numerics.BigInteger in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127565/converting-int-to-from-system-numerics-biginteger-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Update question with example code

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure it fits an integer, then

```
BigInteger big = ...;
int v = BitConverter.ToInt32(big.ToByteArray(false, false), 0)
```

If not, then you have to also do checks and consider endianness of the `big`.

See also meaning of booleans of [`ToByteArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray?view=netcore-3.1#System_Numerics_BigInteger_ToByteArray_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_)

Comment: Updated question to be more precised.  I need universal way to convert between types - specifying all possible conversions to and from `BigInteger`.